# wordpress custom field with link to image not displaying image

Tags: php, wordpress, image

I have a custom post type with a custom field that takes a plain text value that I'm using to pass in a file path for an image inside of my site's /images folder. I'd like to use this to dynamically display an image in the UI based on the post.

```
<div class="page-title-graphic" style="background-image: url(<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'page_title_graphic', true); ?>)"></div>
```

For some reason I'm unable to get the actual image to load. So far, in the custom field I have tried:
`../images/about-header.svg`
and
`/localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/naked-wordpress-master/images/about-header.svg` but have had no luck.

Here's what it outputs to:
[CSS Snippet from Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o162h.png)
Everything looks fine. When I try to open the image in a new tab, I get a new page in my wordpress site that says "Nothing has been posted like that yet!"

Any ideas on why I'm not able to reference the image? Thanks!

Comment: pass the complete path like 'http://localhost/wordpress/..../image.png', you are passing .php as image extension, it wont load

Comment: @charankumar Oops, I'm sorry I made a typo in the post. Instead of ".php" the file is ".svg"

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this,

For custom post type,

```
<?php global $post;
    $query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'YOUR_CUSTOM_POST_TYPE') );
    while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
      <div class="page-title-graphic" style="background-image: url(<?php get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, 'full'); ?>)"></div>
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

I hope this will help you!!!

Comment: Hmm... I don't think I need to loop over my custom post type again. I'm already within a post and just want to display the content of a custom field within the post (which happens to be a file path to an image in my images folder).